# Passing Django data to Require.js module

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

I'm working on a Django webapp and I need to pass data to the Javascript code (I use Require.js) when the page loads. Either I pass the data itself or information that I can later use for querying via Ajax.

I know I could create a global variable in my base.html template like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var djangoData = "{{ data }}";
</script>
```

But it feels wrong to include it in the HTML and it won't be minified/uglified. I don't like to expose the inner logic so explicitly.

Ideally, I would have liked to create a Require.js module that will be populated with the relevant data from Django and that I can optimize (using r.js) and minify.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: That's how I deal with this too and I would love to see some alternative, of course beyond just templating js files.